# Haskell - Extract arguments from infinite list of data

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have the following data structure defined in my haskell code

```
data Exp = Expnum Int - constant
          | Expplus Exp Exp - addition
```

Technically, this expression can have a infinite number of terms. If I would like to extract its terms, how can I do that? (I can't think of a way because I am not sure how to deal with infinite number of arguments in Haskell)

Ex:

```
-- Example: (Expplus (Expplus (Expplus (Expnum 1) (Expnum 2)) (Expnum 3)) (Expnum 4))

extract :: Exp -> [Int]
... -- Not sure how to deal with infinite number of Expnum :(

-- Expected output [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Your example and the data definition seems to be conflicting.

Comment: Yes yes thanks for pointing that out. I have just fixed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct a list where each "leaf" will prepend to the tail, so something like:

```
helper :: Exp -> [Int] -> [Int]
helper (Expnum i) = (i:)
helper (Expplus sa sb) = helper sa . helper sb
```

Now we can use that helper to make a complete list, I leave that as an exercise.